Can Kullback–Leibler divergence KL(P||Q) = KL(Q||P) > 0? RL algorithm implementation
I am implementing the spatial smoothness framework in my RL algorithm (paper). In this framework, I added a noise to the current state (observation) and then calculated the distribution from the noisy state. I intend to calculate Jeffrey's divergence (symmetric KL-divergence). However, I have encountered a situation where KL(P||Q) = KL(Q||P), and both are greater than zero. Is this possible? My code is as follows:
   

from torch.distributions import Normal, Independent, kl

def calculate_spatial_loss(self, minibatch, dist_current):
    
    P = dist_current

    # current observation
    obs = minibatch.obs
    
    # current observation with noise
    obs_perturbed = obs + np.random.normal(0, noise_scale, size=obs.shape)
    
    (mean, std), _ = actor(obs_perturbed)
    dist_perturbed = Normal(mean, std)
    Q = Independent(dist_perturbed, 1)

    # KL-Divergence:
    kl_P = kl.kl_divergence(P.base_dist, Q.base_dist).sum(dim=1)
    kl_Q = kl.kl_divergence(Q.base_dist, P.base_dist).sum(dim=1)
    
    # Jeffery's divergence
    divergence = 0.5 * (kl_P + kl_Q)

    return divergence.mean()


I did:
print(kl_P.mean(), kl_Q.mean())

The result I got is as follow:
tensor(7.8187, grad_fn=<MeanBackward0>) tensor(7.8187, grad_fn=<MeanBackward0>)
tensor(8.3213, grad_fn=<MeanBackward0>) tensor(8.3213, grad_fn=<MeanBackward0>)
tensor(8.8823, grad_fn=<MeanBackward0>) tensor(8.8823, grad_fn=<MeanBackward0>)
tensor(9.2913, grad_fn=<MeanBackward0>) tensor(9.2913, grad_fn=<MeanBackward0>)
tensor(9.8640, grad_fn=<MeanBackward0>) tensor(9.8640, grad_fn=<MeanBackward0>)
tensor(1.0413, grad_fn=<MeanBackward0>) tensor(1.0413, grad_fn=<MeanBackward0>)
tensor(1.0928, grad_fn=<MeanBackward0>) tensor(1.0928, grad_fn=<MeanBackward0>)
tensor(1.1453, grad_fn=<MeanBackward0>) tensor(1.1453, grad_fn=<MeanBackward0>)
tensor(1.2143, grad_fn=<MeanBackward0>) tensor(1.2143, grad_fn=<MeanBackward0>)
tensor(1.2762, grad_fn=<MeanBackward0>) tensor(1.2762, grad_fn=<MeanBackward0>)

which shows both are not zero but they are equal.
Do you think it is possible? and if yes, what this mean? Do you think I am doing something wrong in the code?

Interesting question, however, it's off topic here; try stats.stackexchange.com or math.stackexchange.com instead. A moment's scribbling with pencil and paper suggests that KL(p, q) = KL(q, p) implies integral((p + q)*(log(q) - log(p))) = 0. As to whether there are examples of p and q, with q != p, such that that holds, I can't think of an example at the moment. Maybe working with some specific examples could help, I don't know.

@RobertDodier Let me show you how it is done: the question is off-topic due to not being about programming, and do not try to answer off-topic questions in comments. vote to close off-topic questions.

@Dr.Snoopy Keep fighting the good fight.
